# Two asterisks after the text "Highly active question"

Tags: feature-request

With my reputation, I see a special info box at e.g. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784183/what-does-cdata-in-xml-mean) with two asterisks `**`:

[image]

In my opinion, these asterisks are unnecessary and should be removed.

Comment: This issue has been raised before I think, but unable to find the duplicate question.

Comment: [Already reported on the global Meta's announcement of this feature](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/338509/153008).

Comment: @CodyGray Didn't think of searching there. Sorry for my duplicate .

Comment: Technically not a duplicate... ;-)

Comment: In the footer it should show: `**` *Please wear protective clothing and safety goggles before reading further. Don't touch or feed the post.*